# Is it possible to replicate complex query results with Hibernate API?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have the following table `GOT_CHARS`

```
CHAR_ID     NAME             EVENT_ID
1           Hodor            3
2           Tyrion Lannister  1
3           Ned Stark        5
```

And another table `GOT_EVENTS`

```
EVENT_ID    DESCRIPTION                 EVENT_DT                 SEASON_NBR
1           Drank wine                  1/5/2015 3:04:00 PM      1
2           Plundered                   2/5/2015 3:04:00 PM      2
3           Bought diapers              3/5/2015 3:04:00 PM      2
4           Swung sword                 4/6/2015 3:04:00 PM      1
5           Travelled to Kings Landing  6/7/2015 3:04:00 PM      3
6           Traded for supplies         8/9/2015 3:04:00 PM      1
```

I need to find all first events of a particular season who do not have a referencing character. I came up with the SQL code to do it, but I would like to use Hibernate to map GameOfThronesEvent objects for me, and SQLQuery.list() will not do that.

**So, I either need to be cool and figure out how to get hibernate to map these for me (is this possible???), or be lame and use a manual `ResultTransformer`.**

Here's my sql if you want to try it yourself:

```
create table GOT_EVENTS(event_id number(3) primary key,
                        description varchar2(50) not null,
                        season_nbr number(2) not null,
                        event_dt date not null)

create table GOT_CHARS(char_id number(3) primary key,
                       name varchar2(50) not null,
                       event_id number(3) references GOT_EVENTS(event_id) not null)
```

This is the bit I need to represent with hibernate, either in Criteria or HQL so it will map the stuff from got_events into GameOfThronesEvent objects.

```
with ranked_events as
 (select e.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by e.season_nbr order by e.event_dt) as rk
    from got_events e)
select c.*, re.*
  from ranked_events re
  left outer join got_chars c
    on re.event_id = c.event_id
 where c.event_id is null
   and re.rk = 1;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question... but what are you creating? As a fellow GoT fan, you have my interest haha

Comment: I think that the table values is just sample data not related to the real application.

Comment: There is a way though. If you create a database view with your query and map it on hibernate a a simple table.

Comment: Sorry @Ascalonian the real thing I'm working on is much more boring I'm sorry to say. I just simplified the example the best I could and tried to make it fun. Basically what I'm doing is sending a notification, every time a new event occurs. But I don't want to send a notification for every event, only the first one of a new season.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an SQL query in conjunction with the aliasToBean transformer?

You would need to create a bean that has the relevant fields based on named columns you would return in your query.

Things can get a bit tricky if you need it to map non-standard data types (Dates and enums might cause issues).  Two solutions I've seen in the past are declaring scalar's, or, if that proves too difficult you could try using a setter that accepts a String argument and performs the conversion itself.

Comment: I did look at the AliasToBean ResultTransformer, but my bean has joda DateTime objects in it. So I have to go from java.sql.Date to org.joda.time.DateTime objects. Hibernate might be smart enough to figure that out since it's created from an instant, but I did not test this unfortunately. I assumed it wouldn't work and made my own transformer. Maybe should have tried it.